# How do i send email in zend 2?

Tags: email, zend-framework2

this is my code:

```
    $mail = new Mail\Message();
    mail->setBody('This is the text of the email.');
    $mail->setFrom('Freeaqingme@example.org', 'Sender\'s name');
    $mail->addTo('MYEMAIL@gmail.com', 'Name o. recipient');
    $mail->setSubject('TestSubject');

     $transport = new Mail\Transport\Sendmail();
     $x =  $transport->send($mail);
     var_dump($x); exit();
```

The result of the $x is null. I did not receive any emails. WHY ?

The code with mail() function:

```
                $to = "my_email@gmail.com";
                $subject = "My subject";
                $txt = "Hello world!";
                $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n";

                $x = mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
                var_dump($x);
```

now the result of the var_dump is **(bool)true**, but i did not receive any emails. I also check the spam, but it is empty. WHY ? I'm using xampp localhost server.

Comment: Mail transport send() doesn't return anything, which is why you're getting null. Do you have sendmail installed? If you send with the PHP mail() function (which will also probably use sendmail) does that work?

Comment: please check my post again

Comment: The return value of `mail()` is largely meaningless, as Jurian said, if you're not receiving email from the mail function either, this is not a ZF problem. You didn't answer my question about sendmail - do you have sendmail installed? You may want to try SMTP instead which is generally more reliable.

Comment: hey @MariaMuresan, did you solve this issue..if so pls help me with the link or code..thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [interface for `send()` does not return anything](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/19b8cbafe83b5d86663ed9311809d6fdafa842e4/library/Zend/Mail/Transport/TransportInterface.php#L19-L25):

```
/**
 * Send a mail message
 *
 * @param \Zend\Mail\Message $message
 * @return
 */
public function send(Mail\Message $message);
```

If sendmail failed sending the message, you would probably end up with an exception. At least all errors in the `mail()` function are [captured and collected in a RuntimeException](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/19b8cbafe83b5d86663ed9311809d6fdafa842e4/library/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php#L278-L292).

If you did not receive a message, this is probably due to a misconfigured `mail()` setting. Try to mail yourself simply with `mail($to, $subject, $message)` and check if it arrives. If not (which I guess) this is not a ZF2 problem but a php/mail problem.

Comment: Your initial question was rather "The result of the $x is null. [...] WHY ?", which I explained. If your `mail()` is not working, please create **another question** about the topic. You can't ask two questions in one "question" on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

May be worth setting up postfix and bug testing your mail client via command line.

The following was pretty useful when setting up my local environment: http://traumwind.de/tindertraum/archives/local_mail_osx.html